# question about Taylor series of arctan

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

Since the derivative of $\arctan (x)$ is $1/(x^2 + 1)$, by using the geometric series and
taking the integral term by term, we arrive at
$$
\arctan (x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1} }{2n + 1}.
$$
I know that the radius of convergence is $R=1$.

This is then often used to give a series expression for $\pi$ by evaluating at $x=1$.
What I am confused with is, how do we know that at $x=1$, $\arctan (x)$ is the value of the series evaluated at $x=1$? Just because the Taylor series converges does not generally mean that it equals the function. Any clarification is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: What do you think we use Taylor series for in the first place?

Comment: See [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem). Another way could be to find a bound on the remainder in Taylor's formula in integral form.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 You're missing the whole point. $x=1$ is not in the *interior* of the interval of convergence. The Taylor series need not converge at an endpoint and, a priori, if it converges it might not converge to the value of the function there. This is a common error that students make.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Thanks for your response. I myself am nothing else than a student, so I also made the same error. I will take care next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. Just evaluating the series at $x=1$ is not valid and is a common mistake, but you may use [Abel's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem) to make the argument rigorous.

Answer (score 1):

Michael Spivak's *Calculus* (fourth edition) covers this very topic on pages 420-421, 426-428, and 488-489 in the midst of general discussions and developments for approximating functions with polynomials and infinite sequences and series.

As stated on page 488,
$$
\arctan x = x - \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^5}{5} - \frac{x^7}{7} + \cdots ,
$$
for $|x|\leq 1$. Thus, you can in fact say that
$$
\arctan 1 = 1 - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7} + \cdots ,
$$
However, to get a good approximation of $\arctan 1 = \pi/4$, you need to compute a lot of terms of this series. This is specifically discussed on page 427. For example, Spivak states "To obtain a remainder of $<10^{-4}$, for example, we must take $n>(10^4-3)/2.$, when discussing the Taylor polynomial with remainder for $\arctan$.